# Limits and freeze button aren't working, nor new balls are spawned (Animation)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, animation

This is an UI that makes a ball go down in a diagonal way, but each time I press the button "Animate it!" it doesn't create a new ball.

- Another issue is that the "freeze" button don't work as expected, since it should stop the balls and then; if you press it once more, it ought make the balls move again.
- Finally, something is wrong with the limits as when the ball almost touches the bottom, it doesn´t reach it and bounces to the right side. Also, when the ball "touches" the right limit, it just goes up.
- Additionaly, when the frame is resized, the limits don't update.

Please download a ball and change the directory so the program can find where your ball is allocated. It's not necessary to download the soccer pitch but if you want, it's OK. Finally, I have to thank you for spending time in search of this malfunctioning.

> Ball link: https://lapequeteria.cl/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/balon-adidas-2.jpeg (Make it png)
>
> Pitch link: https://www.freejpg.com.ar/asset/900/9c/9ca2/F100004898.jpg

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

class Animation extends JFrame {  //Frame

  static boolean running = true;
  static Layout panel = new Layout();
  JButton animate, stop;
  Runnable runnable;
  Thread move;

    public Animation() {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());  //BorderLayout disposition
      setTitle("Pelota en acción");      

        animate = new JButton("Animate it!");  //Button to create balls
          animate.setSize(120,30);
          animate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  panel.createEllipse();
                  runnable = panel;
                  move = new Thread(runnable);
                   panel.X = 0;
                   panel.Y = 0;
                  move.start();
               }
          });

        stop = new JButton("Freeze");  //Botón para interrumpir hilo (aun no implementado)
          stop.setBounds(0,0,120,30);
          stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(move.isAlive()){
                  stop.setText("Go");  //Pause
                    synchronized(move) {
                      try {
//                        running = false;
                        move.wait();
                      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Interrupted");
                      }
                    }
                }
                else {
                  stop.setText("Freeze");  //Play
                    synchronized(move) {
//                      running = true;
                      move.notifyAll();
                    }
                }
              }
        });

        JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();  //Layout with its buttons situated to the south
          subPanel.add(animate);
          subPanel.add(stop);
        add(subPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {  //Frame construction
        Animation ventana = new Animation();
          ventana.setSize(850,625);
          ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          ventana.setVisible(true);
          ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class Layout extends JPanel implements Runnable {  //Layout and thread

  volatile double X,Y;  //Coordinates
  volatile double dX=1,dY=1;  //Direction
  static ArrayList<Image> balls = new ArrayList<>();  //Balls collection
  Image picture, ball;
  int width = 120,height = 120;

  @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {  //Shows the ball and the pitch
      super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        soccerPitch();
        g2.drawImage(picture, 0, 0, null);
        for (Image ball : balls) {  //Balls added to the layout
          g2.drawImage(ball,(int)X,(int)Y,100,100,null);
        }
    }

    public void soccerPitch () {  //Builds the soccerPitch image
        try {
          picture = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\NO BORRAR porfavor\\Cancha.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          System.out.println("Pitch image was not found");
        }
    }

    public void createEllipse () {  //Builds the ball image
        try {
          ball = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\NO BORRAR porfavor\\Pelota.png"));
            System.out.println(ball.getWidth(null)+" "+ball.getHeight(null));
        } catch(IOException ex) {
          System.out.println("Any balls were found");
        }
        balls.add(ball);  //Balls are added to the collection
    }

    @Override
      public void run () {  //Moves the ball(coordinate system doesn't work)
        moveBall(Animation.panel.getBounds());
      }

    public void moveBall(Rectangle2D limits) {
        while(true) {
//        while(Animation.running) {
          System.out.println("X: "+X+"\tY: "+Y);
          System.out.println(limits.getBounds());
            X+=dX;  
            Y+=dY;

            if(X<limits.getMinX()){     
              X=limits.getMinX();   
              dX=-dX;
            }
            if(X + width>=limits.getMaxX()){    
              X=limits.getMaxX()-width; 
              dX=-dY;
            }
            if(Y<limits.getMinY()){ 
              Y=limits.getMinY();
              dY=-dY;
            }
            if(Y + height>=limits.getMaxY()){   
              Y=limits.getMaxY()-height;
              dY=-dY;
            }
            try {
              Thread.sleep(4);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              System.out.println("Interrupted");
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Just in case you want to help me; I'm not asking for the work done, just explain me why it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you should change the title of the question. Right now it could attract people who know how to spawn new balls. I think that's not what you want.

Comment: That is what I want xd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to violate basic rules of [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). Plus instead of [using LayoutManagers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) you set the bounds of the components manually (that's why when the Frame is resized, components are not in the right place).

Now, you launch your application in a Thread, right? In this thread, you prepare your GUI and do stuff, and then at some point you `while(true)`. When you `while(true)` the thread will "stuck" inside the while loop, hence swing events cannot take place. That's why you have to `while(true)` and create your animation in another thread. However the best way to create an animation in Swing is to [use a Swing Timer.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

I have created an example where the animation is the creating every 100ms a new random rectangle (10x10) in the panel. Do some expirements with it and try to adjust the same logic to your application (after all, you won't post your code and expect us to fix it for you :) ).

This is the example:

```
public class Animation extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private Timer timer;
    private RectanglePanel panel;

    public Animation() {
        super("test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(panel = new RectanglePanel());

        timer = new Timer(100, this); //every 100 ms add new Shape

        JButton button = new JButton("Start Animation");
        button.addActionListener(e -> timer.start()); //start animation timer
        add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        pack();
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        panel.createNewShape(); //add new shape
        panel.repaint();
    }

    private class RectanglePanel extends JPanel {
        private List<Rectangle> shapes;

        public RectanglePanel() {
            super();
            this.shapes = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public void createNewShape() {
            int x = (int) (Math.random() * getWidth());
            int y = (int) (Math.random() * getHeight());
            x = Math.min(x, getWidth() - 10);
            y = Math.min(y, getHeight() - 10);
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, 10, 10);
            System.out.println("New rectangle:" + r);
            shapes.add(r);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for (Rectangle r : shapes) {
                g.setColor(randomColor());
                g.drawRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
            }
        }

        private Color randomColor() {
            return new Color((int) (Math.random() * 255), (int) (Math.random() * 255), (int) (Math.random() * 255));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //All swing applications must run on their own thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Animation().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

**Preview:**

[image: preview img]

Comment: Thanks, all I wanted was a guide, so that was perfect. Im'm new in this of UI's T_T

Ps: Could you give an upvote to my question if you liked it :)

Comment: @Steve As I see you are a new user. Welcome! Take some time and read [what should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Only one proble. It says in the timer instance that string cant be converted to int and in the list diamond operator that list doesnt take parameters.

Comment: @Steve I did not understand what you mean. :(

Comment: xd I'm 14 years old (just in case as I'm so noob to be an adult)

Comment: @Steve Sharing your age doesn't help me understand what problem you have.

Comment: i was just saying xd

Comment: wait a moment I'll clarify what happened

Comment: above you have alink where you can see the code and what's happening.

Comment: @Steve The `import` of Timer is `javax.swing.Timer` and not `java.util.Timer`

Comment: thanks a lot. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: I fixed the limits, the frame size; but I don't know why when I work with an image it doesnt't create a new ball. The problem seems to be in the g.drawImage() instruction.

Comment: ohhh, now I understand. It creates a new ball but all the instances share the same coordinates. How can I attach one set of coordinates to each ball.

Comment: @Steve Consider asking a new question for it. Trying to solve your problems in comment section is not easy.